# background-image repeat pattern is showing side effects when pattern size is small

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to create a table pattern using background image, it works fine when cell size is 50px * 50px but when I go below 25px * 25px few rows start to disappear or get fainted.

What is the reason behind this & how can it be fixed?

[At 25px * 25px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Gat.png)

[At 50px * 50px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frfiV.png)

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  height: 713px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  /*background-size: 50px 50px;*/
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/_GG.svg");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/arnavsingh/pen/bGWPqXP

Note: It gets fixed when I zoom in using browser settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

such task is now trivial with only one gradient:

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  height: 713px;
  width: 400px;
  --b:1px; /* adjust this */
  background:
    conic-gradient(at bottom var(--b) right var(--b),#000 75%,#0000 0) 
    0 0/25px 25px /* and this */
    pink;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way i can think of, is to set your widht and height to some math size with variables.

For example your height will be like
`height: $someSize * 10; background-size: $someSize $someSize ;`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the line in your svg can't be rendered at the smaller size (as the border becomes less than 1px).

Why not try using a linear gradient instead (change the 25px for whatever size square you want):

```css
div {
  height: 713px;
  width: 400px;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
        transparent 0  calc(25px - 1px),
        #AA8087 calc(25px - 1px) 25px),
        
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
        transparent 0 calc(25px - 1px),
        #AA8087 calc(25px - 1px) 25px)     
    #FFC0CB;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Your theory makes sense, thankyou so much. Also thankyou for introducing me to repeating-linear-gradient I had no idea such a thing exists.