# How to draw a grid with background-image

Tags: css, codepen

I'm making a CSS 3D viewer on Codepen [CSS 3D viewer (zoom, rotate, pan)](https://codepen.io/eternalsunshineofspotlessmind/pen/bGRdPoz?editors=0010) but I feel like I didn't get quite right the grid on the floor.

I've used the following approach:

```
background-image:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    #BADFEB 0,
    #BADFEB 2.5%,
    #0000 2.5%,
    #0000 47.5%,
    #BADFEB 52.5%,
    #BADFEB 52.5%,
    #0000 50%,
    #0000 97.5%,
    #BADFEB 97.5%
  ),
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    #BADFEB 0,
    #BADFEB 2.5%,
    #0000 2.5%,
    #0000 47.5%,
    #BADFEB 52.5%,
    #BADFEB 52.5%,
    #0000 50%,
    #0000 97.5%,
    #BADFEB 97.5%
  );
```

I've noticed some lines are thicker than others and some lines disappear on zoom out.

I would like to keep tiles of 1em of side length, with all lines of equal thickness and without them disappearing.

What kind of strategy could I use to achieve something as close as possible as a grid on a cad software?

Thanks

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68833766/8620333

Comment: Could you use some `div`s in the HTML and then use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)? I've created Tic-Tac-Toe boards like that b4. LMK, if that might work and I might share some code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is a good solution, how does it work?

Comment: @CodeFinity interesting but it seems overkill for this, I knew there was a way with gradient. Would I gain some benefit by using CSS Grid?

Comment: make the background-repeat no-repeat to understand the pattern. It's a basic conic-gradient with two colos

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've just noticed the solution you referred to doesn't work as I would expect, when changing the background-size to a multiple of my base unit the grid doesn't match. Why?

Comment: @CodeFinity I tried your suggestion but I ended up discarding it as it require to fill up the grid with elements. Thanks you anyway

Comment: You have to have some `div`s to start. I thought it might be a bit simpler as you are literally trying to create a `grid`, instead of forcing `linear-gradient` to look like a grid.

Comment: @CodeFinity I have to thank you because your solution is perhaps helping me with another bigger issue than this one. Basically I want to map Xs and Yx of mouse to relative coordinates of the scene but I'm finding it quite challenging since the damn thing is transformed, but I think I can make a grid and map coordinates with CSS (or use some JS).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. You might be interested in manipulating `grid` values with [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) I'm interested to see how it turns out. Realistically, I might even be able to fiddle with it during this upcoming long weekend, so keep posted.

Comment: @CodeFinity I initially used CSS Grid then I've stopped because it slowed down my fiddle by A LOT. Take a look at the fiddle now... It's running quite smoothly :) I've settled for the linear-gradient in the end... Just changed its values to fix the bugs mentioned in the question.